# Seperating emails in outlook using python or c#

Tags: c#, python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I need to separate email conversation thread to individual email in outlook and, I need to process those individual emails for signature ,I'm unable to find any resources regarding this. I have gone through win32com, python library but I am unable to get my requirements.

Comment: Would be easier in .net than python. You could make an outlook addin, but that's a bit of a distraction. Looks for ".net outlook interop" and have a go. We'll help fix problems, but you have to try first.

Comment: Get whut? We won't write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a rule that moves email messages based on the sender or recipients of an email message.

[try this](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/merge-split-conversations/)